# How can I set a default setCatchHandler with Google Workbox v4?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox

I want to set a default setCatchHandler with Workbox v4.0.0-rc.0. I tried

```
importScripts('./workbox-v4.0.0-rc.0/workbox-sw.js');

workbox.setConfig({modulePathPrefix: './workbox-v4.0.0-rc.0'});
workbox.navigationPreload.enable();

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    new RegExp('/icons/'),
    new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({cacheName: 'icons'})
);

workbox.routing.setCatchHandler(({event}) => {
    console.error('setCatchHandler', event.request.destination);
});
```

It does not seem to work as I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: workbox.routing.setCatchHandler is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong? The official documentation says this is the way to go (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes#provide_a_fallback_response_to_a_route)

Comment: Thanks for testing out v4—this is a bug, tracked at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/1897. We'll get it fixed!